# If I spun a ring singularity on two seperate axis would it become a sphere? If so, then how fast?

Tags: black-holes, singularities

I know that a spinning a black hole creates a ring, so does spinning a ring singularity in a additional axis at a sufficiently speed create a hollow sphere if so at what speed?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. What do you mean by a ring and ring singularity for a spinning black hole?

Comment: A kerr black hole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3(+1) dimensions, an object can be stationary and rotating only around a single axis. You see this yourself, try to throw solid spinning objects in the air and you should be able to see that their motion can be decomposed into

1. the motion of their center of mass,
2. rotation around an axis, and
3. more complicated motions of their rotational axes due to torques

When you have an isolated, freely floating object, 3. will be eliminated. You can then transform into the center-of-mass frame where the object's only motion is rotation around a single axis. So, in 3+1 space-time dimensions, it does not really make sense to talk about objects (black holes included) rotating around more than one axis.

But that does not need to stop us, theoretical physicists have been considering more than 4 space-time dimensions for quite some time. Let's just look at 5 dimensions for simplicity. There it turns out that the doubly rotating singularity does not have a topology $S^2$ but rather the torus (surface of a doughnut or a tire) $S^1 \times S^1$. This makes a lot of sense, because if you stop rotating around one of the axes, the singularity in that direction collapses to a point and we get the topology $S^1 \times point = S^1$. However, we have $S^1 \times S^1$ for any arbitrarily small rotation about the second axis (this answers a part of your question).

On the other hand, if we were to say our singularity has the topology $S^2$, the transition from a sphere $S^2$ to a ring $S^1$ could not be continuous and some kind of weird jump would have to occur in the transition from a doubly rotating black hole to a black hole rotating only around one axis. So, even though I am not aware of any rigorous proofs of this statement, I would expect that $S^1 \times S^1$ and higher dimensional analogies are the only possibility for multi-rotating black hole singularities.

Answer (score 1):

A Kerr Black Hole is one of the 4 solutions(for Black Holes) to General Relativity where this one is for a rotating black hole  with an inner and outer **Event horizon** forming a so called *ring* around it. Matter itself **does not** form a ring around it, rather the curvature of spacetime around matter allows such a build of a field up. Space time behaves in such a way that  as Kerr Black Holes have complicated geometries and a temporal singularity leading to a theoretical 'negative space'.

The link below you can read much more on Kerr Black Holes including diagrams:

[Kerr Black Holes](http://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/K/Kerr_black_hole.html)

Comment: But the singularity itself is a one dimensional ring is it not?